# How do I get Sitecore (and my browser) to use the Print layout?

Tags: asp.net, http, printing, sitecore, sitecore6

I am adding some support to print specific pages of my site in a nice printer-friendly format.  So the first thing I did was create a more-or-less blank Layout that I can drop content into.  Then I went to a content page and assigned this layout to the "Print" device in Presentation Details.

That does not seem to do anything.  I'm still getting the exact same output on Print Preview that I saw before I defined any Print settings.  To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how this should work.  Presumably, my browser has to request the page again with a new user agent (???) to get Sitecore to return a different rendering of the page... but I've tried Firefox, Chrome, and IE and get the same undesired output from my "Default" device.

Must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Print device, by default, will be used when there is a `?p=1` querystring value on the page you want to print. The print preview in the browser is simply previewing the page with the Default device.

Try putting that querystring in the address and see if you get the layout you are expecting.

As you noted, there is the ability to switch Device via a Browser Agent, but that won't be useful here. That would mainly be used for mobile device detection.

Comment: Aaaah... yep, missing something very easy.  Thanks Sean.

Comment: Basically you can find out what makes it use a certain layout on the devices, which can be found in:

/sitecore/content/layout/devices/

Det default printlayout is called Print and has a querystring that is "?p=1" as Sean writes, but you can change this.

Comment: Adding ?p=1 to the URL works fine for me to get the layout I'm expecting, but printing from the browser (without "?p=1" in the URL) still doesn't resolve to the Print layout. What am I missing? Do I need to configure device detection somewhere else, other than on the 'Query string' property on the Print device?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to edit the target, as per this link: [Use OnBeforePrint Window Event Handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint). There might be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

To access print device dynamically on anchor click, do following

default.aspx

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlPrintLink" runat="server">
</asp:hyperlink>
```

//default.aspx.cs

```
HospitalDirectionsPageItem objHospital = Sitecore.Context.Item;   
         string deviceName = "print";
            DeviceItem deviceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().Where(d => d.Name.ToLower() == deviceName.ToLower()).First();

            if (deviceItem != null)
            {
                hlPrintLink.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(objHospital) + "?" + deviceItem.QueryString;

            }
```